# GAE - PHP7 - how to pass GET parameters by front-controller

Tags: php, google-app-engine

Google Apps Engine for PHP7 now requires a "front-controller". These are the URL I need to manage:

> - /sitemap.xml
> - /app/myPHP ?param1=value &param2=value2

my source folder has the following files

> - index.php (front controller)
> - home.php
> - gen_sitemap.php
> - myPHP.php

so I coded my front-controller (index.php) as

```
<?php
switch ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) {
    case '/':
        require 'home.php';
        break;

    case '/sitemap.xml':
        require 'gen_sitemap.php';
        break;

    case '/app/myPHP':
        require 'myPHP.php';
        break;

    default:
        echo "no page " . time();
        break;
}
```

But it is not parsing correctly the URLs:

> https://myProject.appspot.com/ --> home.php ok
>
> https://myProject.appspot.com/?p="hello" --> no page
>
> https://myProject.appspot.com/sitemap.xml --> sitemap.php ok
>
> https://myProject.appspot.com/sitemap.xml?p="h" --> no page
>
> https://myProject.appspot.com/app/myPHP --> myPHP.php ok
>
> https://myProject.appspot.com/app/myPHP?p="h" --> no page

How do I fix this front-controller?

Comment: Should I change $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] for $_SERVER["PATH_INFO"] ?

Answer (score 0):

The Switch condition may not work properly since it is comparing "REQUEST_URI". The PHP's SERVER global variable key REQUEST_URI will probably have the full path with the query string. Rather try the key "SCRIPT_NAME" or "PATH_INFO"

Suggestion: First check what all key values are available in the $_SERVER variable then choose which key value to use for adding your switch command.

Example: print_r($_SERVER);   as the first line of your code

Reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php